# The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'

Tags: dart

```dart
Map<String, int> score_map = {
    'A': 1,
    'E': 1,
    'I': 1,
    'O': 1,
    'U': 1,
    'L': 1,
    'N': 1,
    'R': 1,
    'S': 1,
    'T': 1,
    'D': 2,
    'G': 2,
    'B': 3,
    'C': 3,
    'M': 3,
    'P': 3,
    'F': 4,
    'H': 4,
    'V': 4,
    'W': 4,
    'Y': 4,
    'K': 5,
    'J': 8,
    'X': 8,
    'Q': 10,
    'Z': 10
};

int score(String word){
    int score = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        _score += score_map[word[i].toUpperCase()];
    }

    return score;
}
```

I am new to Dart but not new to programming but I can't figure out what's with the error here. The int type `_score` is initialized with a value, it's not `null`, so I am not sure why I keep getting the error:

`The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.`

Especially since I've explicitly declared the map as `<String, int>`. I understand `num` is the umbrella type for both `int` and `float` in Dart, but why is the analyzer inferring this as `num` at all if it's explicitly defined as `<String, int>`? Is this a bug?

I've tried changing int to num in the map as well as for the variable `_score`. That only seems to make it think that I've a `num?` somewhere in the expression.

Comment: `score_map[word[i].toUpperCase()];` is null if `word` is not found in the `score_map` and the compiler has no way of ensuring that only valid `words` are passed as parameter ...

Comment: Can't there be something like a KeyError when that happens, like how Python does it?

Comment: It had to mimic JavaScript closely.  You can use something like Map.update if you want to have a fallback for an absent item.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz `putIfAbsent` would be more appropriate, though if you don't want to mutate the underlying collection, just use a null-coalescing operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a null safety issue for the case where the letter is not found in the map.

One solution is to change your `_score` assignment to be:

`_score += score_map[word[i].toUpperCase()] ?? 0;`

The `?? 0` provides a default value to ensure `_score` is always assigned to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is a bit nuanced.

First is the obvious part. When you fetch a value from a `Map` using the indexer, the resulting type is going to be nullable. This is to cover the case where the request key doesn't exist in the map, in which case, the indexer will return `null`. (This is in contrast to other languages that might just throw an error.)

So what you're actually doing in this part of the code is this:

```dart
int? value = score_map[word[i].toUpperCase()];
(int) _score += value; 
// ^^ Note the assignment of a nullable value to a non-nullable variable
```

And since `_score` is a non-nullable variable, trying to assign a nullable value to it is going to result in an error.

The second part is less obvious, but the reason is that, in Dart, compound assignment operators don't actually exist. Instead, they are syntactic sugar for the expanded operator form, meaning that `X += Y` is just syntactic sugar for `X = X + Y`. This makes your actual code effectively this:

```dart
_score = _score + value;
```

Also in Dart, `int` extends `num`, and as such, the signature for the `+` operator is:

```dart
num operator +(num other);
```

So when you do addition of any two numbers in Dart, you are actually calling this function on the first number and passing the second number as the argument to the function. (This is the high-level explanation. In practice, the exact behavior depends on the platform the code is compiled for.)

With all of that put together, this is what you are doing in a nutshell (no, this isn't legal Dart code, it's just for demonstrative purposes):

```dart
String key = word[i].toUpperCase();
int? value = score_map[key];

_score = _score.+(value); // The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.
```

This is also because the type of `value` is a nullable `int?`. Otherwise, an `int` can obviously be passed to a function that expects a `num`.

With the explanation out of the way, the solution is that you need to practice some null-safety on the map indexer. One approach would be to use a null-coalescing operator to provide a default value if the requested value doesn't exist:

```dart
_score += score_map[word[i].toUpperCase()] ?? 0;
```

More advisable, however, is to check if the key exists beforehand, and if it doesn't, define alternate behavior.

```dart
final value = score_map[word[i].toUpperCase()];
if (value != null) {
  // Dart will promote `value` to a non-nullable variable in this block
  _score += value;
} else {
  print('Could not find a score for "${word[i]}".');
}
```